# Setting navigationBar title font of the next view? Help with "setTitleView" to some label?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to set the title font of my navigationBar, so I can change the font size, because I want a longer title... I do it like:

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        UILabel *navTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        [navTitle sizeToFit];
        [navTitle setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30]];
        [navTitle adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth];
        [navTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [navTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [navTitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [navTitle setText:@"SuperLongTitleOfMyNaviBar"];
        [self.navigationItem setTitleView:navTitle];

    }
    return self;
}
```

The place where the title should be is empty... Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: why do you need this UILabel? you just write directly to the titleview your string.

Comment: cause it wont fit :) it's too long... this way, the label automatically resizes the text to fit

Comment: Can you post `setting text alignment, color, bg color, etc. here...` code?

Comment: you might want to do this in the detail VC in this case. Check out this tutorial - very helpful: http://www.icab.de/blog/2009/10/13/adding-any-kinds-of-ui-elements-into-a-uinavigationbar/

Comment: @Kashiv and others, I just completely reedited my question, to make it more clear and universal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, at the time you call `sizeToFit` label has no `text`. So the `frame` won't get changed.

You should be calling `sizeToFit` method after you assign the `text` to the label.

Comment: If you want `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to work, you have to explicitly set the `frame` of the label.

Comment: no... it worked for me if I did `naviTitle.adjustFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` strange... :) nice thanks anyway

Comment: Yes. `[label adjustsFontSizeForWidth]` is a getter method. To set value you should use `[label setAdjustsFontSizeForWidth:YES]`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set frame of your label - replace

```
UILabel *navTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
```

with

```
UILabel *navTitle = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 32)] autorelease];
```

You can replace `CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 32)` with your values.